# Expected distance of point uniformly drawn from unit ball $B_r(1)$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

For some time now I fight with an exercise I received. I have to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\vert\vert Z \vert\vert_2]$ and $Var[\vert\vert Z \vert\vert]$, that is the expected distance as well as variance from the point Z to the origin, within the d-dimensional unit ball $B_d(1)$ with radius 1. Here, Z is uniformely drawn from this unit ball.

Of course I know the definition of the expectation of a $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued random variable, i.e. 
$$(\mathbb{E}[Z])_i = \int_\mathbb{R^d} x_i\, p(x) dx $$

yet I have no idea how to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\vert\vert Z \vert\vert]$ or $Var[\vert\vert Z\vert\vert]$. What to do here?

EDIT: The answer is given as $\frac{d}{d+1}$. The actual task is to prove that this is the solution.

Comment: have a look at the very pedagogical document (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/CStheory-infoage/chap1-high-dim-space.pdf)

Comment: The pdf for the distance from the center should just be the derivative of the $d$-ball's volume as a function of the radius, normalized by the total volume of the ball.

Comment: Thanks, JeanMarie! A very useful resource!

Answer (score 1):

The key is to first get the pdf $f_R(r)$ of $R = ||X||_2$. As [the answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2488534/612568) suggests, the $f_R(r)$

> will be proportionate to the surface area of a sphere at that radius

In the excellent document pointed out by @Jean Marie, you will find that $V(d,r) = r^dV(d,1)$, where $V(d,r)$ is the volume of a ball of radius r, and $V(d,1)$ is also given but irrelevant for our purposes. They also show the following relationship
$$
V(d,r) = \int_0^r A(d,x) dx
$$

with $A(d,x)$ the surface area of the ball of radius $x$. Differentiating yields
$$
A(d,r)= dr^{d-1} V(d,1)
$$

Thus, it follows that $f_R(r) \propto r^{d-1}$. Note that this is proportional to the pdf of a Beta$(d,1)$ distribution. You can then get the expected value and any other properties from this relationship.