# PDF in Unit Ball

Tags: probability

Let $z = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ be a random point, written in rectangular coordinates $x_1, x_2, x_3$, chosen from the uniform distribution on the interior ofpthe unit ball in 3 dimensions.
(a) What is the probability density of the distance $R = \sqrt{(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2)}$? 
(b) What is the probability density of the first coordinate $x_1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the geometry interpretation.

(a) The ball is uniformly distributed, therefore the proability *density* of $r:=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ will be proportionate to the surface area of a sphere at that radius; ie $f_R(r)\propto r^2$ for some constant of proportionality that ensures $\int_0^1 f_R(r)=1$.

(b) Likewise the probability density of the $x_1$-ordinate will be proportionate to the area of the *disk cross-section* perpendicular to that axis at that ordinate; that is $f_{X_1}(x) \propto \underline{\textit{what?}}$, and ensuring $\int_{-1}^1 f_{X_1}(x)\mathrm d x=1$.